# How do I install macports successfully?

Tags: install, macports

Right now it's stuck at

> Running packages scripts

And here is the log:

```
Aug 28 13:48:52 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: MacPorts base version 2.1.2 installed,
Aug 28 13:48:52 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: MacPorts base version 2.1.2 downloaded.
Aug 28 13:48:52 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: --->  Updating the ports tree
Aug 28 13:48:52 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
Aug 28 13:48:55 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: receiving file list ... done
Aug 28 13:48:56 Alejandro installd[9247]: ./postinstall: ports.tar
```

How do I successfully install macports? I don't see any bandwidth transfer and I cannot exit the setup.

Comment: like if you are watching this question in 2015